# Adding an optional OrderBy to compiled entity framework linq queries

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4, lambda, expression-trees

We have a collection of compiled Entity Framework linq queries that we use to access our SQL data (usual model of static class members).

In certain situations we now have the requirement to provide optional orderings to some of these queries and ALSO have these as compiled entity framework queries.

Now it would be quite easy to just dupe up the compiled queries and create ones for the order by scenarios but we would much prefer to keep a 'base' Expression and then 'append' the appropriate OrderBy to it.

Now this seems to be easily achievable when you aren't using compiled queries.  Similarly i've tried using the AsExpandable extension from Linqkit but the entity framework compiler doesn't seem to like it.

Anyone got any pointers on how i can achieve this (without masses of code wandering down expression trees)?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the (still in CTP, but out RSN) EF for .NET 4.5, which transparently compiles all queries by default, without need for explicit use of `CompiledQuery`. I don't think there's a go-live license just yet, but if you're willing to wait you get this for free.